# Not all attributes binding to ng-model

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have a form in an app I'm building that allows a user to submit their name and email. This form is duplicated on two tabs (on the same page). Here's the basic form:

```
<form class="user-submit-form" ng-submit="userSubmit(user)" ng-hide="userSubmitted">
  <h4><strong>FOR THE CHANCE TO HAVE YOUR STORY DRAWN, TELL US YOUR NAME AND CONTACT METHOD.</strong></h4>
  <span>Entries limited to one caption per cartoon per person.</span>
  <br>
  <input type="text" title="Name required" ng-model="user.name" size="32" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="email" title="Email required" ng-model="user.email" size="32" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" title="Must agree to Terms & Conditions" class="terms" 
         required><span>I have read and accept the Terms & Conditions</span>
  <br>
  <input class="user-submit-stories user-submit" type="image" src="images/submit_name.png">
</form>
```

When I make changes to the user.name attribute the both of the forms update the value. However, when I update the user.email attribute the other form's value is not updated. I've also noticed that when I try to explicitly define the model's attributes in the related controller, the change is not made in the form for user.email

What could be causing a situation where one attribute is properly binded but the other is not?

Comment: Are the forms in two different controllers perhaps? Or a parent-child?

Comment: There's a parent controller, BaseCtrl, then there's two children, CaptionCtrl and StoriesCtrl. The two forms are inside scope of the two children controllers, respectively. User is initially defined as an empty object in BaseCtrl as $scope.user = {};

Comment: Verrry interesting... think you can repro this in a Plunkr - my guess is the controller relationship is off somewhere, hard to tell without code tho

Comment: i don't get it. type="email" wont bind the object [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUYqco7GePWsbFZrIvhc?p=preview)

Comment: Are you saying a model can't be bound within an email input?

Comment: no, sorry. it has to be a valid email .. lazy testing, my bad

Comment: Angularjs won't bind to model unless the value is valid. Your problem is similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793070/how-do-i-prevent-angularjs-from-unbinding-a-form-inputs-value-from-its-model-wh

Comment: @hutingung, this was 100% the problem. Thank you! Out of curiosity do you know where this is in the Angular documentation? I couldn't find anything specific to this.

Comment: @RyanB, I also don't know. I try to find but I also can't get it. I get to know this by testing the behaviour and read the code. IMHO, I think the code is the best documentation.