# ng-minlength and ng-pattern preventing binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have defined an input feild as

```
<form name="signUpForm">
<input type="text" name="username" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="64" ng-model="user.username" ng-pattern="/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^]))/">
</form>
```

And defined user in controller as

```
$scope.user{};
```

Now when I bind user.username value in HTML, its preventing it.

```
<p ng-if="user.username.length > 0">Display True</p>
```

Even if I simply bind its value in HTML as

```
{{user.username}}
```

Its not being displayed.

Now if I remove ng-pattern from input field as :-

```
<input type="text" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="64" ng-model="user.username">
```

then only its binding and that too after satisfying ng-minlength="8" condition. Means '12345678' is displayed and '1234567' not.

One more issue is there i.e. if I use ng-pattern then ng-minlength validation is not working.

```
<p ng-if="signUpForm.username.$error.minlength">Please enter minimum length</p>
```

Comment: I haven't bothered trying to guess what this regex accepts and rejects, but what you're seeing is expected: until the entered string doesn't pass all the validation rules, the model is undefined. So, for example, Seeing nothing until the entered string is at least 8 characters is normal and expected.

Comment: Ok what about non functioning of ng-minlength when ng-pattern is being used ?

Comment: Works fine here (with a regex I understand): http://plnkr.co/edit/cGFUmixvOP5GI5UdEOBH?p=preview. Enter only lowercase letters: the value will appear only after you type 4. Enter an uppercase letter: the value disappears.

Comment: Yes, that's because your username must contain at least one number, one lowercase character, one uppercase character and one character  from @#$%. Try to type "test1@Test" and angular will bind it.

Comment: Ok. Might be there is some error with my regex.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `form.$viewValue.length` instead of the model's length

for example:

```
<p ng-if="signUpForm.username.$viewValue.length">Display True</p>
```

here's a solution I found:
[How do I prevent AngularJS from unbinding a form input's value from its model when it's invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793070/prevent-unbinding-a-form-inputs-value-from-its-model-when-invalid)