# ui-grid use only editable cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want a ui-grid where you can edit directly without changing the template.

I tried to override the cellTemplate with the standard of the editable celltemplate, but it isnt getting dirty now.

```
<div><form name="inputForm"><input type="INPUT_TYPE" ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"></form></div>
```

So i dont want to show the cellTemplate instead i want to show the editable cellTemplate only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks totally possible to me, just make sure your `field` attribute contains no unusual symbols (dash or dots mainly, use only letters to be on the safe side).

Look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiHik7eFe20inDEX636H?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for validating this. For anyone else who comes to this question, one thing to check in your code as compared to the working plunkr linked to above is to make sure you are using ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" not something like ng-model="row.entity.myProperty" otherwise you won't see the value change.

Comment: Another thing to check in code that isn't working is whether you have min or max attributes on your input. If a user enters a valid outside that range, Angular won't update the bound ng-model property. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676461/dont-record-invalid-values-with-ng-model/18676747#18676747